# why the android log cant be shown by the tag “CDMA” and “GSM”

Tags: android, logging

I'm trying to make use of logcat to println something.

The code is as following:

```
String tag="CDMA".

log.D("tag","blablabla")
```

but the output will be nothing....
and if I change "CDMA" to "aaa", it can be shown. Is there anybody can explain it?
Thanks...

Comment: If you'd do this, you'd get the tag `tag` I guess... Shouldn't `log.D("tag","blablabla")` be `log.D(tag,"blablabla")` ?

Answer (score 2):

A few searches with Google Code Search and I found this:

```
/* XXX: This needs to go! */
if (!strcmp(tag, "HTC_RIL") ||
    !strncmp(tag, "RIL", 3) || /* Any log tag with "RIL" as the prefix */
    !strcmp(tag, "AT") ||
    !strcmp(tag, "GSM") ||
    !strcmp(tag, "STK") ||
    !strcmp(tag, "CDMA") ||
    !strcmp(tag, "PHONE") ||
    !strcmp(tag, "SMS"))
        bufID = LOG_ID_RADIO;
```

So, a tag with any of these values are treated specially as coming from the radio, which I'm guessing logcat supresses for our benefit (since radio activity is out of our control and may saturate the log with irrelevant messages).

Answer (score 0):

Your log was probably working. It was just going in the radio log.  You can see it by typing 
logcat -b radio -v time